# Send array to server starting with iOS 7

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I need to send many variables to server. Previously I was using construction like this:

```
let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com");
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myURL!);
request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

let postString = "param1=\(var1)&param2=\(var2)"

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

Now I need to send not only variables like param1 and param2 but few arrays. I know that there is library called Alamofire but it is not supporting iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
let mapDict = [ "a":"First", "b":"Second"]

let json = [ "title":"kk" , "dict": mapDict ]
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

// create post request
let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/post")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// insert json data to the request
 request.HTTPBody = jsonData


 let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){  data,response,error in
 if error != nil{
    println(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
if let responseJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject]{
    println(responseJSON)
}
}

task.resume()
```

You can use array instead of dictionary as per your requirement. hope this will help. :)

Comment: thank you, but this code is not working with Swift 2 and Xcode 7. It needs try blocks and few more changes